# Python Requests Data Error?

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

I'm using requests and BeatifulSoup to retrieve and extract information from a webpage.

However, when I call requests.get(url) and then print out the text result, it is not the same as what I see when I 'Inspect Element' on the webpage. Multiple sections of HTML code are missing, some tags have "Loading" in the span etc.

I suspect this means the requests.get() function is pulling the data from the page before it is fully loaded.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're only pulling the HTML for that page. The odds are that the HTML loads javascript which manipulates the DOM. Compare your inspecting to the "View Source" or curl output.

Comment: @Jack Yeah, I just realised that the output is identical to the Page Source. Is there a way to get the data generated by the javascript?

Comment: Sure. Use something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: ` requests.get() ` does not load the data which is manioulated by JS ... you will have to use Selinium to load page as a Browser loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, what you are seeing in the browser via inspecting is HTML which may have been rendered with javascript.

Your code:

```
requests.get(url)
```

Is the raw response from the server. The javascript has not yet rendered and provided you with dynamically created HTML.

As mentioned in the comments, if you require your program to render this page you may want to try Selenium, PhantomJS, QT4, or Ghost.

Selenium: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

PhantomJS: https://github.com/elias-winberg/phantomjs-python

Ghost: http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/

Scraping with QT4: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/